# Titanium Mobile 3.0 Navigation Controller pass variables between windows

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I am using swanify's Titanium Navigation Controller https://github.com/swanify/Titanium-Navigation-Controller for my app deployed in Android device.

i am trying to pass data that i have selected from a table row here back to the previous page and populate a text field there.

Anyone has any ideas how to do it? i am looking into using events but it doesnt seem to be working for me.

thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have done in this situation, It makes use of the eventing aspects of JavaScript and Titanium, the general principle is to have your own custom events, fire them on a control, and listen elsewhere.

First lets say we have a file named `NextWindow.js` that is a CommonJS module encapsulating a window and a tableview, everytime the a row is clicked we capture that event, then fire our own custom event *on the window*:

```
function NextWindow() {
    var self = Ti.UI.createWindow();
    var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView();
    // Other initialization
    ....
    ....
    tableView.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        // You may have to use e.rowData.title depending on how you created the table view
        var rowTitle = e.row.title;
        // Now fire a custom event on the window whenever a row is selected
        // send the title through as data
        self.fireEvent('table_row_selected', {title : rowTitle});

    });

    return self;
}
module.exports = NextWindow;
```

When you create a `NextWindow` to push onto the navigation stack, add a listener for a custom event to it, this is inside of the previous window with the text box:

```
var NextWindow = require('NextWindow');
var nextWindow = new NextWindow();
nextWindow.addEventListener('table_row_selected', function(e) {
    // Do what you want here with the passed back data 
    var title = e.title;
    some_label.text = title;
});
// Open the next window on the NavigationController stack
nav.open(nextWindow);
```

Now were listening for a custom event attached to the `nextWindow`. Say you have a TableView in your `nextWindow`, listen for the TableView click, and fire the custom event:

Comment: works like magic. thank you very much sir. the only additional thing i did was to do `self.close()` after firing the event. :)